# Having a playlist of songs that shuffle automatically on a website with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

Is there a way to have a playlist of songs (Around 6 songs) that are shuffled and played on a website through javascript, html, or css? I've been able to get some songs to play over each other and to play automatically upon visiting the website, but there's no way to make any songs play in a row, much less have a randomized/shuffled order for them to play in. The music automatically plays through a .mouseenter (hovering) function where it's able to play one song, but that's it. I can't find nor figure out any way to make it play one after the other, or for them to be shuffled.
I'm somewhat new to coding so any and all help/advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

HTML code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hidden">
    <a href="#">.</a>
    <audio id="flame" preload="auto">
        <source src="flame.mp3">
    </audio>
</ul>
<script>
        var flameOne = $("#flame")[0];
        $(".firesong")
        .mouseenter(function() {
  flameOne.play();
});
</script>
```

Comment: An audio element has an [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event that you can use to start the next song.

Comment: Adding on to @Ivar 's comment, you can dynamically create 'audio' elements and push those into an array, then setup the ended event listener and start the next song in the array.